# C: variadic functions with void pointers

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm new to C and trying to create a variadic function that takes in void pointers. However, I'm getting some unexpected behavior that I don't really understand...

**token.h**

```
typedef struct {
    int (*funcOne) (void*, ...);
    ...
} symbols_t;
```

**main.c**

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
} job_t;

int job_create(void* objPtr, ...) {
    char* name;
    int i = 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, objPtr);

    while(&objPtr[i]) {
        void* arg = va_arg(args, void*);
        if (arg == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        printf("arg %u: %s\n\n", i, arg);
        i++;
    }
    va_end(args);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void) {
    symbols_t symbolTable;
    symbolTable.funcOne = *job_create;

    job_t myJob;

    // See output one
    symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, "hey1", "hey2", "hey3", "hey4", "hey5", "hey6", "hey7", "hey8);

    // See output two
    symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, "hey1", "hey2");

    // See output three
    symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, "hey1");

    // See output four
    symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output one:**

[image]

**Output two:**

[image]

**Output three:**

[image]

**Output four:**

[image]

Any insight into what's happening here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to pass `NULL` as the last argument.

Comment: There is no guarantee anywhere in that `va_arg(args, void*);` will return a nullpointer, you have to explicitly add a terminating `NULL` in the function call

Comment: Also, I'm fairly sure `&objPtr[i]` is undefined behaviour. You just go into whatever memory lies after `objPtr`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, those arguments are of type `char *`, not `void *`, and the final argument ought to be `(char *)NULL`.  It's unlikely to make a difference on most machines, but `void *` could in principle be passed in a different way from `char *`, and `NULL` can be defined as `(void *)0` or even `0` which would cause it to be passed as either `void *` or `int`, not `char *` unless you cast.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: @UnholySheep That worked. What does adding NULL terminate and why is it needed?

Comment: @Siguza Does adding NULL make it so it's no longer going into the next memory block?

Comment: Just look at your code: you loop until `va_arg` returns `NULL`.  Since `va_arg` is successively returning the arguments passed to the function, it will return `NULL` only if you actually passed `NULL` as an argument.  If you thought the compiler would add it automatically, or that it would keep track of how many arguments were passed and return `NULL` when they ran out, you are mistaken.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah I wrote it, I thought there was an implicit `NULL` if it got to the end. Isn't that how `char*` works? if it gets to the end it'll see `\0` which you would check for and not have to explicitly pass in yourself?

Comment: @Garrett: There is a null byte at the end of **each** of the strings.  That is not the same as saying there is a **null pointer** as one of the **arguments**.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yup that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation, I've been banging my head against a wall.. If you post that as the answer I'll accept

Comment: @Garrett No, `&objPtr[i]` will always be wrong. You seem to be under the impression that something known is adjecent in memory to your `void` pointer. That is not the case.

Comment: If all arguments are void pointers, and the last argument needs to be a NULL value, you could argue that you might as well have passed an array of void pointers instead of using a variadic function.

Comment: @Cheatah Sure, what would be the benefits / trade-offs between those two approaches?

Comment: The array has several advantages: you get type safety back (no risk of an undetected type mismatch between `va_arg` and what you actually pass).  And it is likely to be more efficient, since variadic calling conventions are often rather clumsy (e.g. spilling registers or copying stack that may not even be used), and the loop over the array can be optimized better since the element sizes are known in advance.  The only real downside is that you need another line or two of code before the call to create and initialize the array (or use a compound literal which has slightly awkward syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks for `va_arg` to return `NULL` in order to exit the loop, and that would only happen if you actually explicitly pass `NULL` as an argument.  The compiler doesn't magically add it. As such, after running through the arguments actually passed, the loop continues reading arguments that aren't there, which is undefined behavior (a likely outcome is that you read whatever garbage is in the unused registers or memory).

So your call should look more like

```
/* still not quite right, see below */
symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, "hey1", "hey2", NULL);
symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, NULL); /* pass no strings */
```

However, a couple points to make your program more correct: a string literal has type `char *`, not `void *`, so there is a mismatch between the type actually passed and the type you request from `va_arg`.  That causes undefined behavior, in general.  Your `job_create` function should instead be doing `char * arg = va_arg(args, char*);`.

Then, passing `NULL` as the last argument is not quite right.  The macro `NULL` is allowed to be defined as either `(void *)0` or simply `0`.  That leads to the same mismatch in either case: your `va_arg` is now expecting `char *`, but what's being passed is either `void *` or `int`.  The latter case is particularly dangerous on machines where `int` is smaller than a pointer.

You need to pass a null pointer of type `char *`.  So the correct way to call this function would be:

```
symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, "hey1", "hey2", (char *)NULL);
symbolTable.funcOne(&myJob, (char *)NULL); /* pass no strings */
```

Comment: In the case that function's variadic arguments might not always be of type `char*` is `void*` then correct?

Comment: @Garrett: Again: the type requested by `va_arg` must match the type actually passed.  That type can be `void *`, if you want to allow pointers to objects of various actual types, but then you must ensure that `void *` is actually passed.  Which will probably require calling the function like `funcOne(arg, (void *)"hey1", (void *)"hey2", (void *)&other_object, (void *)NULL);`.

Comment: @Garrett: And on the other side, you'll have to cast the return value of `va_arg` back to the correct type to actually access the object.  For example, `printf("arg %u: %s\n\n", i, arg);` is wrong if `arg` is `void *`, because the `%s` specifier expects `char *` and not `void *`.  You would have to cast it to `char *` to pass it to `printf`.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, if the function were to accept an array `void*` instead of being variadic, would that mean arguments wouldn't have to be passed in as `(void *)"hey1"`?

Comment: @Garrett: Generally speaking, `char *` will be converted to `void *` without a cast, in a context where the compiler can tell that `void *` is expected.  The issue is that when calling a variadic function, the compiler has no idea what is expected.  But for instance, if you write something like `void *array[] = { "hey1", "hey2", "hey3", NULL }; job_create(array);` then no casts are needed.  Inside `job_create` you still have to cast the pointers back to `char *` if you want to use them as strings.